# How to calculate the gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

$$
f(\mathbf{q})=\mathbf{q}^T\mathbf{H}^T\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{q} & 0\\ 0 & \mathbf{q}\\ \end{bmatrix}
 \left(\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{q} & 0\\ 0 & \mathbf{q}\\ \end{bmatrix}^T\mathbf{G}^T\left(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{q}^T\mathbf{q}^T\right)\mathbf{G}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{q} & 0\\ 0 & \mathbf{q}\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{q} & 0\\ 0 & \mathbf{q}\\ \end{bmatrix}^T\mathbf{H}\mathbf{q}
$$
where $
\mathbf{q}\in\Bbb{R}^{4\times 1}$, $\mathbf{H}\in\Bbb{R}^{8\times 4} $, $\mathbf{G}\in\Bbb{R}^{4\times 8}$.
How can I calculate $\nabla f(\mathbf{q})$?

Comment: I once had a nightmare and it looked pretty simmilar to that expression...cross my heart!

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Nop. I just woke up, had some cake and completely forgot about it...until you reminded me of it!

Comment: You can calculate the gradient by a number of tedious applications of the chain rule.

Comment: If you have access to matlab, the symbolic toolbox there is good for this sort of thing

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions!